# How to specify a direct color in a tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, gradient

I want to model gradients in TikZ for a paper covering color gradients. These are rather special, so a cannot rely on a TikZ shade alone. Thus, I want to model the gradient using consecutive TikZ shaded rectangles, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{tikzpicture}\shade[left color=red,right color=gray]
  (1.211,0.000) rectangle (0.211,1.000);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, instead of red and blue I need an RGB color triplet as common in HTML. As per `xcolor` manual 2.3.3, I figured

```
\shade[left color=rgb,300:red,51;green,41;blue,5,right color=rgb,300:red,50;green,38;blue,0]
```

might do the job, but I get `` ! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `rgb'. ``

It is feasibe but really awkward to pregenerate all the colors I need. Is it possible to use `xcolor` direct colors in a TikZ shade? all the examples I came across either use definecolor (even for HTML colors) or named colors.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not so difficult to create shortcuts for such recurring commands. And you can create and recreate the same color, here is a quick mock-up; you can get the setting you are trying push rgb syntax to and read off the argument of the assignment and place it to a temporary color name. Then use it for the setting of that key.

I don't know how often you will use this and for what so no promises.

**EDIT**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{xcolor/.code args={#1=#2}{
     \definecolor{mytemp}{rgb}{#2}
     \tikzset{#1=mytemp}
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[xcolor={left color={0.5,0.7,0.1}},xcolor={right color={0.7,0.4,0.8}}] 
(1.211,0.000) rectangle (0.211,1.000);
\shade[xcolor={right color={0.5,0.7,0.1}},xcolor={left color={0.7,0.4,0.8}}] 
(0.211,0.000) rectangle (-1.211,1.000);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

the edited image

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this looks very promising! (I'll test in a few hours.)

Comment: Thanks, this works. In fact I found putting the extended color spec in braces also works, syntactically, but I fail to get RGB on that path, so I ended going with your solution.

Comment: Or, perhaps not. If looked like it worked but it does not scale as I require. The next parts of the gradient (adjacent tikz shades) do not show up at all. Only one shade seems to work with the trick.

Comment: @SimonThum I don't know what you require so you need to make a case for me. Otherwise it does work.

Comment: It's simple; do an adjacent shaded rect like the first, and try to make it show up. There are no latex errors AFAICT but the second shadeed rectangle does not show up in the PDF.

Comment: @SimonThum Is this what you mean? I really don't get your intention. Please make a MWE and add it to your question that resembles your actual problem.

Comment: Yes, you got it precisely right. Your example works over here but not mine, I guess that validates the approach but I still have other problems. I guess I should have some sleep first ;)

Comment: Like it, but somewhat find the resulting "post-fix" syntax counter-intuitive. IMHO, it should be `left color={xcolor={0.5,0.7,0.1}}` instead of `xcolor={left color={0.5,0.7,0.1}}`.

Comment: @Daniel That needs fixing all TikZ keys that accepts color.

Comment: Thanks again, I figured it out (a misunderstanding of how tikz coordinates work) and it works great!